# Week timetable: PHP in_array or jQuery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, timetable

No actual code is required in the answers, only good advices for best practices.

What I need is to display a week timetable (1h timeslots) in a Bootstrap website for booking purposes. The timeslot will have one of the following status:

- Available: green background and 'available' text,
- Already booked: red background and 'occupied' text,
- Not available for booking: gray background and 'not available' text.

When a user clicks on an available timeslot a modal/popup will appear for booking.

Only one week is displayed (= current week). Eventually the user can click on an arrow and view next week timetable. So, I have no need to display more than the current and next week.

**I have thought of three possible solutions:**

1. Create a MySQL table with one record for every available timeslot (automatically with a cronjob). This way I can just print the table data in the frontend. *Note: I've already done this and works great but not optimal if you have many timetables in the site.*
2. Use a jQuery plugin (like Fullcalendar). Apparently even if what I need is super-simple, Fullcalendar (or other calendar plugins) are not meant for this kind of usage. Even with a lot of customisation, you cannot do this.
3. Build the timetable dynamically with PHP using the `in_array()` function.
   The idea is to create two MySQL tables, one for storing non-available hours and the other for reservations.

   With two simple queries I can obtain 2 arrays (for the week currently displayed): 'non_available_timeslots' and 'reservations'.

   When I build the week timetable (normal bootstrap table), for each timeslot I will control 2 things:

   a) If the day/hour is in the array of 'non_available_timeslots' (if so

   ```
   echo '<td class="not-available">Not available</td>'
   ```

   .....else continue to point b)
   b) if the day/hour is in the array of 'reservations' (if so,

   ```
   echo '<td class="booked">Occupied</td>'
   ```

   .....else continue to point c)
   c) if the 2 above conditions are not matched,

   ```
   echo '<td class="available"> Available</td>'
   ```

As you can see what I want to do is really simple. **I'm interested in solution 3**.

From a performance point of view, is it bad? (Note that the absolute max number of elements to search between in the in_array function would be equal to the number of timeslots in the timetable, so 15x7= 105, but in reality probably only 50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post you've already decided what solution you'll use. Given this, I would only create one table with a column (`status`) that would be different for "Not available" and "Occupied".

I would use only one table because you might need another status in a few days / weeks / months. You can always have more than one array with values from the same table.

I don't think you have to consider performance with that ammount of rows (or timeslots). I say: go with it and adjust as your application grows up.

Comment: I have only understood what you truly meant right now. It is genial!! Yet, using only 1 table is not always possible (depending on the web app structure and functionalities). Anyway, when indeed it is possible, it is truly the right way to go!! Thank you very much